# How to output HTML within JS variable as HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, variables, output

I was wondering if someone could help me, I created this JavaScript variable called embed it contains some HTML. I was wondering how I would go about outputting the html in the variable.

`var hostname = "http://www.justin.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel="+channelname+"\" id=\"live_embed_player_flash\" height=\"700\" width=\"1280\" bgcolor=\"#000000\">http://www.justin.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf\" />"`

Anyone who can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What kind of output html do you want? can you give an example of what should end up in the page?

Comment: I cut it off by accident it posted it in the comments on the response below. It's an embed code, I'm trying to get it to display the video player embed on a page. After a user feeds the channel name. If you are willing to help I can let you look at my live editor with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output your HTML inside another element:

```
document.getElementById("parent-element").innerHTML = hostname;
```

Comment: I've tried that and then placed <div id='parent-element'></div> in the body after doing that, but nothing happens. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @user2036348 Your `hostname` is not valid HTML - you need to have `< ></ >` or `< />` and you only have `> / >`.

Comment: <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"http://www.justin.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel="+channelname+"\" id=\"live_embed_player_flash\" height=\"700\" width=\"1280\" bgcolor=\"#000000\"><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"/><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\" /><param name=\"allowNetworking\" value=\"all\" /><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.justin.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf\" /><param name=\"flashvars\" value=\"hostname=www.justin.tv&channel="+channelname+"&auto_play=false&start_volume=25\" /></object>"

Comment: I just cut it off by accident

Comment: @user2036348 Make sure `channelname` is set and that your embed is linking to a URL that actually exists. If you're still having problems after that, I can't really help without seeing more of your source code - the JS I provided is fine and should work properly.

Comment: If I share the code with you, would you be willing to take a look?

Comment: http://urloritdidnthappen.appspot.com/370001 This is a live code editor, Sorry about the Google Apps allow page.

Comment: @user2036348 All of your JS code is executed as the page loads. Meaning that your code is trying to insert HTML into `#div1` before it even exists, and never again. Move your closing bracket so that your function encompasses all of the code to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost with that could you elaborate?